# Symbol or notation for quotient operator

Tags: notation, integer-programming

I'm trying to describe an algorithm in pseudocode where I've used the integer division operator. In VB.NET, the language I'm using, the operator used is "\", but I don't know if this is unambiguous to the reader that this symbol means "integer division". I've also seen "div" used. I can't use TeX or anything complicated format-wise. Is there an accepted symbol or notation for integer division operator, so that it very clearly means "integer division" and not regular division?

Comment: In math, $\setminus$ usually refers to set difference (LaTeX: `\setminus`), but if you mention it in the context of integers or natural numbers, it should be clear what you mean. To be absolutely sure, just write it as a remark ("Where I use \ to denote integer division")...

Comment: div an mod maybe

Comment: @LeoKing done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In math, $\setminus$ usually refers to set difference (LaTeX: `\setminus`), but if you mention it in the context of integers or natural numbers, it should be clear what you mean. To be absolutely sure, just write it as a remark ("Where I use \ to denote integer division")

Another common notation, especially in the context of ${\rm mod}$ as the complementary operation, $\mathop{\rm div}$ is widely used.

Comment: Or just spell it out each time: subtract off the remainder (mod) and divide.